# Can't change images based on onClick

Tags: javascript

I have created a small basic Javascript which will change the image with the use of arrows image. Below is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Title</title>
</head><body>
<img class="draw" src="images/website-drawing-scan.png" alt="Main">
<h1>New idea!</h1>
<img class="left" src="images/left.png" height="50" width="40" style="float: left" alt="Left"> <img class="right" src="images/right.png" height="50" width="40" style="float: right" alt="Right">
<p>Hello! This is John with a trial test new website! Try this and you might soon be able to finish their work. </p>

<ul>
    <li>First thing to do</li>
    <li>Second thing to do</li>
    <li>Third thing to do!</li>
</ul>
</body>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

And below is the script main.js

```
let myHeading = document.querySelector("h1");
myHeading.textContent = "Hello World!";

let myImage = document.querySelector("draw");

let left = document.querySelector("img.left");
let right = document.querySelector("img.right");

left.onclick = function () {
    if (myImage.getAttribute("src") === "images/website-drawing-scan.png") {
        alert("No more images!");
    } else {
        let width = myImage.width;
        let height = myImage.height;
        myImage.setAttribute("src", "images/firefox.png");
        myImage.setAttribute("width", width);
        myImage.setAttribute("height", height);
    }
};

right.onclick = function () {
    if (myImage.getAttribute("src") === "images/firefox.png") {
        alert("No more images!");
    } else {
        myImage.setAttribute("src", "images/website-drawing-scan.png");
    }
};
```

Now whenever I click on the arrows (left.png) or (right.png), nothing happens while the code is written to change the image based on the click of left arrows. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I am sure there is an error message in the console when you click

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your selector is not working because there is no such HTML element as `draw`, you probably want `img.draw`

```
let myImage = document.querySelector("draw");
```

In general, you should be able to solve such problems yourself by verifying what your code is doing, i.e. that your variables are being populated with the correct values. A simple `console.log(myImage)` would have probably shown you the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select an element called `draw` for your variable `myImage`. What you are looking for is an element with a class name `draw`. you need to change `querySelector('draw')` to `querySelector('.draw')`

I've also changed your `onClick` function to take arrow function, to make sure the variable are accessible from the current context.

```js
let myHeading = document.querySelector("h1");
myHeading.textContent = "Hello World!";

let myImage = document.querySelector("img.draw");

let left = document.querySelector("img.left");
let right = document.querySelector("img.right");

left.onclick = () => {
    if (myImage.getAttribute("src") === "images/website-drawing-scan.png") {
        alert("No more images!");
    } else {
        let width = myImage.width;
        let height = myImage.height;
        myImage.setAttribute("src", "images/firefox.png");
        myImage.setAttribute("width", width);
        myImage.setAttribute("height", height);
    }
};

right.onclick = () =>  {
    if (myImage.getAttribute("src") === "images/firefox.png") {
        alert("No more images!");
    } else {
        myImage.setAttribute("src", "images/website-drawing-scan.png");
    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Title</title>
</head><body>
<img class="draw" src="images/website-drawing-scan.png" alt="Main">
<h1>New idea!</h1>
<img class="left" src="images/left.png" height="50" width="40" style="float: left" alt="Left"> <img class="right" src="images/right.png" height="50" width="40" style="float: right" alt="Right">
<p>Hello! This is John with a trial test new website! Try this and you might soon be able to finish their work. </p>

<ul>
    <li>First thing to do</li>
    <li>Second thing to do</li>
    <li>Third thing to do!</li>
</ul>
</body>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a misprint on the JavaScript code, but you miss a dot on your query selector. It should be:

let myImage = document.querySelector(".draw");

for a valid CSS selector.

[document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)